# If $S'$ is a subring of $R'$, then $f^{-1}(S')$ is a subring of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the question:

> Let $f: R \to R'$ be a (ring) homomorphism. If $S'$ is a subring of $R'$, then $f^{-1}(S')$ is a subring of $R$

Doesn't $f$ need to be an isomorphism and not just a homomorphism? My proof so far:

---

(Closed under addition) Take $f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(b) \in S$. Then 
$$
f^{-1}(a) + f^{-1}(b) = f^{-1}(a + b)
$$
and since $S'$ is a subring, $a + b \in S' \implies f^{-1}(a + b) \in R$.

---

but this only works if $f^{-1}$ is an isomorphism. Am I missing something?

Comment: As you say, this only works if $f$ is an isomorphism because in general, $f^{-1}(a)$ is a set of elements, so $f^{-1}(a)+f^{-1}(b)$ is not an element of the ring. Instead, what happens if you take two elements $a,b\in f^{-1}(S')$ and add them together, can you show that $a+b\in f^{-1}(S')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to work with this definition of the inverse image/preimage.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29)

$$H=f^{-1}(S') = \{x\in R | f(x) \in S'\ \}$$

Now show

$e\in H$

If $x,y\in H$ then $xy^{-1}\in H$

Thus $H$ subring of $R$